# Add real data into Bar Graph: Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, mpandroidchart

I have very easily created a bar chart using MPAndroidChart library and experimented with the example below. I am struggling to find information on how to link real data from my application to this bar graph. Example, a score keeper app. How to plot the daily final scores on the bar graph for team a and team b? My app displays the scores for both teams but how to I transfer that displayed final score into this code below? (I've only been doing android development for 6 weeks).

```
 /*Displays the given score for Team A.*/
    public void displayForTeamB(int score) {
            TextView scoreView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.team_a_score);
            scoreView.setText(String.valueOf(score));
        }


    repositories {
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    }

    dependencies {
        compile 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v2.0.9'
    }

    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                    tools:context=".MainActivity">

        <com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.BarChart
            android:id="@+id/chart"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    package com.truiton.mpchartexample;

    import android.graphics.Color;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;

    import com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.BarChart;
    import com.github.mikephil.charting.data.BarData;
    import com.github.mikephil.charting.data.BarDataSet;
    import com.github.mikephil.charting.data.BarEntry;
    import com.github.mikephil.charting.utils.ColorTemplate;

    import java.util.ArrayList;

    public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            BarChart chart = (BarChart) findViewById(R.id.chart);

            BarData data = new BarData(getXAxisValues(), getDataSet());
            chart.setData(data);
            chart.setDescription("My Chart");
            chart.animateXY(2000, 2000);
            chart.invalidate();
        }

        private ArrayList<BarDataSet> getDataSet() {
            ArrayList<BarDataSet> dataSets = null;

            ArrayList<BarEntry> valueSet1 = new ArrayList<>();
            BarEntry v1e1 = new BarEntry(110.000f, 0); // Jan
            valueSet1.add(v1e1);


            ArrayList<BarEntry> valueSet2 = new ArrayList<>();
            BarEntry v2e1 = new BarEntry(150.000f, 0); // Jan
            valueSet2.add(v2e1);


            BarDataSet barDataSet1 = new BarDataSet(valueSet1, "Brand 1");
            barDataSet1.setColor(Color.rgb(0, 155, 0));
            BarDataSet barDataSet2 = new BarDataSet(valueSet2, "Brand 2");
            barDataSet2.setColors(ColorTemplate.COLORFUL_COLORS);

            dataSets = new ArrayList<>();
            dataSets.add(barDataSet1);
            dataSets.add(barDataSet2);
            return dataSets;
        }

        private ArrayList<String> getXAxisValues() {
            ArrayList<String> xAxis = new ArrayList<>();
            xAxis.add("JAN");
            xAxis.add("FEB");
            xAxis.add("MAR");
            xAxis.add("APR");
            xAxis.add("MAY");
            xAxis.add("JUN");
            return xAxis;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

By looking at your code, you can already set basic graph interface. So I'm only writing code for what you need to assign entries for your score line which would look like this sample from my code.

```
     // creating list of entry
        ArrayList<Entry> entries = new ArrayList<>();
        entries.add(new Entry(100f, 0));
        entries.add(new Entry(1000f, 1));
        entries.add(new Entry(600f, 2));
        entries.add(new Entry(1500f, 3));
        entries.add(new Entry(3500f, 4));


        final LineDataSet dataset = new LineDataSet(entries, "");
        dataset.setDrawCircles(true);
        dataset.setDrawCubic(true);
        dataset.setLineWidth(7f);
        dataset.setValueTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorAccent));
        dataset.setColor(Color.parseColor("#ED1A4D"));
        dataset.setValueTextSize(14f);
        dataset.setCircleColor(Color.parseColor("#ED1A4D"));
        dataset.setCircleRadius(7f);
        dataset.setCircleColorHole(0);

// creating labels
        final ArrayList<String> labels = new ArrayList<String>();
        labels.add("12AM");
        labels.add("06AM");
        labels.add("12PM");
        labels.add("06PM");
        labels.add("12AM");


        List<ILineDataSet> dataSetslist = new ArrayList<ILineDataSet>();
        dataSetslist.add(dataset);

LineData data = new LineData(labels, dataSetslist);


lineChart.setData(data); // set the data and list of lables into chart
        lineChart.animateY(1500);
        lineChart.setDescription("Daily report");
        lineChart.setScaleEnabled(false);
```

Hope it helps you if you still need more help feel free to comment.

Comment: Thanks. I still don't understand how to modify the code to add real time data from user inputs. It's just beyond my scope of understanding at this moment. I'm trying to do too much with such little experience. Thanks anyways.

Comment: No worries! everyone has to start somewhere. . . I am also a beginner trying to be intermediate. If you want I can provide you complete sample code.